# Probability- determining the number of possible teams with person A being in the same team as either B or C

Tags: combinatorics

There are $8$ people, let's name them $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H$. In how many ways can we form two indistinguishable $4$ person teams such that person $A$ is in the same team as either $B$ or $C$?

**My answer:**

I made a Venn diagram in order to determine what exactly do I need to calculate and it looks like I need to calculate the sum $$|A∩B| + |A∩C| - |A∩B∩C|$$

Where $|A∩B|$ is the number of possibilities we can put person $A$ and $B$ together into one team and so on. Next- let's put person $A$ into a team first. Now we've got $3$ spare places in the team person $A$ is in, so the probability of person $B$ getting into one of them is $\frac{3}{7}$. Then I multiplied $\frac{3}{7}$ by $\binom{7}{3}$, since it's the number of ways we can place all $7$ remaining people into $3$ spots in the team and the result I got is $15$. This result is gonna be the same for calculating $|A∩C|$, so the final answer is $$15 + 15 - |A∩B∩C|$$
Now it's time to calculate $|A∩B∩C|$. I figured the chance that both $B$ and $C$ get into the same team with $A$ is $\frac{3}{7}$ * $\frac{2}{6}$. Now I need to multiply that by $\binom{7}{3}$ and the result is $5$. After plugging it into the equation I get $$15 + 15 - 5 = 25$$
as the final answer. Is my reasoning correct?

EDIT: To avoid further confusion, "either" is an inclusive OR in this context.

Comment: Assuming "*either B or C*" is to be interpreted as it is allowable for it to be both, i.e. as an *inclusive or*, yes your answer and approach is correct, though it could be presented more cleanly by exclusively using counting arguments and avoiding mentioning probability.  Note that $15 = \binom{6}{2}$ can be calculated directly in one step rather than two steps with one of the steps being probability like you had.  In the event that "*either...or*" is to be interpreted as the **exclusive or**, then you need to subtract $|A\cap B\cap C|$ an additional time.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, it is inclusive. How to interpret getting the answer instantly by calculating $\binom{6}{2}$ though? I don't really see it.

Comment: "Assuming the case that $A$ and $B$ are both in the group then we have **six** remaining people and need to **choose two** more people to fill out the group.  There are **six-choose-two** ways to do this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *true blue anil* mentioned in their answer, there is a case to be made that the question intends A should be in the same team as B or C but not both.

You (OP), on the other hand seem to have gone with the other interpretation - at least one of B and C have to be in the same team as A.

Taking your interpretation, here one way to solve the problem.

Total number of ways in which two teams (indistinguishable) of $4$ can be made from a group of $8$ is

$$\frac{\binom{8}{4}}{2} = 35$$

And the number of ways in which the two teams can be formed such that A is in one team and B and C in another is (the complement of what the question states)$^*$

$$\binom{5}{2} = 10$$

So, the number of ways of forming the teams such that A has at least one of B and C as a teammate is

$$35 - 10 = 25$$

Which is what you got.

---

$^*$ We put B and C in one team and A in another. Then we choose the two teammates for B&C in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways.

Comment: Another way to see that there are $35$ ways to divide $8$ players into two indistinguishable $4$-person teams is to choose one player (say $A$) arbitrarily and note there are $\binom 73=35$ ways to choose $A$'s teammates.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you! I like this one better - less calculation and more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Treating "... person A is in the same team as either B or C" to be an exclusive OR as per common English usage, and that either B ot C *must* be on $A's$ team, I compute it to be

($A,B+ 2$ from $5$) + ($A,C, 2$ from $5$)

$= \binom52 + \binom 52 = 20$

If, on the other hand, an inclusive OR is intended, add  the inclusive combo to $20$, viz.

$20+ (A,B,C + 1 \; from \;5) = 20+ \binom51 = 25$

Comment: I'm assuming the opposite meaning of "either" and it's mostly my fault at translating, but I totally get how $20$ is the correct answer when treating it as an exclusive "or". I got the same answer when treating it this way. Your solution also helped me understand how to solve this problem quicker, but just as intuitively.